# HTML/CSS - Attach a box while scrolling another

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a webpage based on Bootstrap.

Consider this code:

```
<section id='#top'>
</section>

<section id='#center'>
  <div class='row'>
    <article id='myArticle' class='col-md-8'>
      <!-- Content -->
    </article>
    <aside class='col-md-4'>
      <!-- To attach while scrolling the content of myArticle -->
    </aside>
  </div>
</section>

<section id='#bottom'>
</section>
```

I'd like to fix the `aside` block but only while scrolling the content of `myArticle`.
To give you an example:

[image]

Do you have any suggestion in this regard? How can I do it?

Comment: This one? https://codepen.io/ncerminara/pen/eKNROb

Comment: Yes, thanks! I'll give it a try!

Comment: Sure :) Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Glad to hear :)